# Turn CSV Table with Excel

Tags: excel, csv, transformation

I don't know if I'm right here. My problem is, I have to turn a CSV table using Excel.

Pictures may explain that better:

this is an example of an initial table:

[image]

and I want the new table look like that:

[image]

Any idea what function can do this!?

I would really appreciate your help, because my paper is due tomorrow and I need the table for a statistical calculation.

Comment: take a look at =sumif and =countif

Comment: looks like an excellent situation for a [pivot table](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/datamanagementinexcel/tp/090929-excel-pivot-table-tutorial-hub.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with a Pivot Table.

Thank you Sean Cheshire for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUMIFS()` on the restructured data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your example but you may have to move them in pieces (not all at once) but copy all of the cells.. right click "Paste Special" -> "Values" -> Checkbox "Transpose" (in the paste special dialog box). This will transpose a block of cells.